# rest request not processed by zuul

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

The zuul service isn't even called for the routing, direct requests work.

zuul : localhost:8900
service : localhost:38000
(the routing works when i use a url for request but not if I use the following method from the resttemplate:

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType, Map<String, ?> uriVariables) throws RestClientException {
    Type type = responseType.getType();
    RequestCallback requestCallback = this.httpEntityCallback(requestEntity, type);
    ResponseExtractor responseExtractor = this.responseEntityExtractor(type);
    return (ResponseEntity)this.execute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor, uriVariables);
```

any idea how i make zuul listen to this request?

Comment: maybe your zuul definition is incorrect. check your route in your zuul properties file.

Comment: but if it would go so far (what i don't belive) i would see a PUT request in the log.

2016-08-04 15:52:15.581  INFO 22791 --- [0.1-9000-exec-5] c.p.m.zuulgate.filters.pre.SimpleFilter  : GET request to http://localhost:9000/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/findByNameLike

works fine - then i want to modify what i've got as a result and use the rest method you see in the question.